# Combobox value increment and update

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7

I have made a custom add-in for my building ID update tool. The objective is:
user will write an alphanumeric value in the combobox like 'x100'. When a user selects a bunch of polygons(building) and click on the button, it should increment its numeric part and update the value in the Build-ID column of the attribute field.

The code so far is:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class Pid(object):
"""Implementation for Group Building ID Updation_addin.Pid (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        Pid.items = [""]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        Pid.items[0] = Pid.value
    def refresh(self):
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

class updateid(object):
"""Implementation for Group Building ID Updation_addin.updateid (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        if Pid.items[0] != "":
            sel = ""
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
            layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
            for layer in layers:

                try:
                    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
                    if desc.FIDSet:
                        sel = layer.name
                        break
                except AttributeError as e:
                    print("FIDSet failed on layer - {}".format(layer.name))

            if sel != "":
                if arcpy.Describe(sel).FIDSet:
                    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(sel, "Build-ID") as curs:
                        for row in curs:
                            num1 = int(filter(str.isdigit, x)) + 1
                            str1 = str(filter(str.isalpha, x))
                            Pid.items[0] = str1 + str(num1)
                            row = (Pid.items[0],)
                            curs.updateRow(row)
                else:
                    pythonaddins.MessageBox('No Selection', 'INFO', 0)
                arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
            else:
                pythonaddins.MessageBox('No Selection', 'INFO', 0)
        else:
            pythonaddins.MessageBox('Please Enter Previous Building ID', 'INFO', 0)
```

This tool sends below error when loading it.

```
>>>
File "<string>", line 1
Group Building ID Updation_addin.Pid=Group Building ID Updation_addin.Pid()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When writing a value in combobox it sends below error.

```
>>> 
TypeError: unbound method onEditChange() must be called with Pid instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)
>>> 
TypeError: unbound method onFocus() must be called with Pid instance as first argument (got bool instance instead)
```

When clicking on the button it says.

```
>>> 
TypeError: unbound method onClick() must be called with updateid instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Has anybody have any idea where it is failing.

Edit: I've tried making an instance of Pid class and called the method through it, but the errors remain same.

Comment: @user2856 Didn't help.

Comment: @user2856 same errors are showing up.

Comment: @user2856 It worked!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your filename has no spaces, i.e can't be called "Group Building ID Updation_addin".
2. You're trying to call the class `Pid`. You can't do this.  You need to create an instance of it, `my_pid = Pid()` then use `my_pid.items` inside `updateid` and `self.items` inside the Pid class.